# how to use dispatchQueue.main to pass value out of closures in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, closures

i need some clarification regarding passing values out of closures. I think the issues is to use dispatchQueue.main but I cannot understand where and why

here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var allCard = [Card]()    
let card = Card(name: "", cost: 0, attack: 0, durability: 0, cardClass: "", cardSet: "", imageURL: "", goldenImageURL: "", type: "", mechanics: [["":""]], howToGetGolden: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCards()
    print(allCard.count)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func getCards()  {
    let url = URL(string: "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards/sets/Classic?mashape-key=....")!        
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil { // if urlSession have issues manage the error here
            print(error)
        } else { // if we have data, response, error then continue here
            if let urlContent = data { // if data exist then
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                    for cards in 0...jsonResult.count - 1 {
                        if let name = jsonResult[cards]["name"] as? String {    //NAME Optionaml Bindings
                            self.card.name = name
                        } else {
                            self.card.name = ""
                        }                                                       // END Name Optionaml Bindings
                        if let cost = jsonResult[cards]["cost"] as? Int {       //COST Optionaml Bindings
                            self.card.cost = cost
                        } else {
                            self.card.cost = 0
                        }                                                        // END COST Optionaml Bindings
                        if let attack = jsonResult[cards]["attack"] as? Int {    //ATTACK Optionaml Bindings
                            self.card.attack = attack
                        } else {
                            self.card.attack = 0
                        }                                                       // END TTACK Optionaml Bindings
                } catch { //catch error while parsing json
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        } // end if/ELSE
    } // end of task (closure)
    task.resume()
}
}
```

How should I use dispatchQueue.main here? And is it async or synch? I tried to check on internet but I couldn't find an answer I understood /:

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is your actual issue? that `print(allCard.count)` is `0`?

Comment: yes and then to keep all the card data in the allArray

Answer (score 3):

Your download takes time, so you will have to wait for it to finish to be able to print the results. To do so, add a completion handler to `getCards()`:

```
func getCards(completion: () -> Void)  {
    // ... your code
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        // ... your code
        for resultDict in jsonResult {
            // create a new card ...
            let card = Card(name: resultDict["name"], cost: resultDict["cost"], attack: resultDict["attack"], durability: 0, cardClass: "", cardSet: "", imageURL: "", goldenImageURL: "", type: "", mechanics: [["":""]], howToGetGolden: "")
             // ... and actually add it to your array
             allCard.append(card)   
        }
        completion() // call completion after parsing 
    } // end of task (closure)
    task.resume()
}
```

and call it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCards() {
        // the code in this closure is called after the download finished
        print(allCard.count)
    }
}
```

---

Update:

`URLSession` `dataTask` calls it completion handler on the background queue. So if you have to do UI stuff (which must be handled on the main queue) you have to dispatch your call of the completion handler on the main queue:

Replace:

```
completion() // call completion after parsing
```

with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    completion() // call completion after parsing 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I tought I had to use dispatchQueue for doing this.

Comment: You do not need a dispatchQueue using this approach.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `dataTask` calls the completion handlers on the same queue on which the task has been started, right?

Comment: ... as long as you do not do UI stuff, which has to be handled on the main queue.

Comment: And what if I would like to update a tableview with the data from the array? Is this method working the same?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected your code for you. Better way is to move your cards to func and make it returns cards or nil if it fails via closure. And also you don't need to set empty string and 0 in "else"s because you card already initialized with these "default" values. Also you'll now have two arrays - one local in func, just recently downloaded cards. And second - class instance variable that will hold all ever downloaded cards.

Escaping means that your closure can be executed after func returns(in this case when request will be done).

[weak self] - I added it because your view controller might not exists when request will be done, so closure won't keep it in the heap and let it go (for example when you tired to wait response from server and just clicked back or cancel and dismissed this view controller).

Also I executed completion on the main thread so you can update UI right in the closure.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var allCards = [Card]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCards() { [weak self] cards in
        if cards != nil, self != nil {
            self!.allCards.append(contentsOf: cards!)
            print("Downloaded cards on this session \(cards!.count)")
            print("All downloaded cards \(self!.allCards.count)")
            // you can update UI here
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func getCards(completion: @escaping ([Card]?)->Void)  {
    let url = URL(string: "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards/sets/Classic?mashape-key=....")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in

        var cards: [Card]? = nil

        if error != nil { // if urlSession have issues manage the error here
            print(error ?? "")
        } else { // if we have data, response, error then continue here
            if let urlContent = data {

                cards = [Card]()

                do {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                    for cards in 0...jsonResult.count - 1 {

                        let card = Card(name: "", cost: 0, attack: 0, durability: 0, cardClass: "", cardSet: "", imageURL: "", goldenImageURL: "", type: "", mechanics: [["":""]], howToGetGolden: "")

                        if let name = jsonResult[cards]["name"] as? String {    //NAME Optionaml Bindings
                            card.name = name
                        }                                                       // END Name Optionaml Bindings
                        if let cost = jsonResult[cards]["cost"] as? Int {       //COST Optionaml Bindings
                            card.cost = cost
                        }                                                       // END COST Optionaml Bindings
                        if let attack = jsonResult[cards]["attack"] as? Int {    //ATTACK Optionaml Bindings
                            card.attack = attack
                        }

                        cards.append(card)

                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(cards) }
                } catch { //catch error while parsing json
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        }
        if cards == nil {
           DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(nil) }
        }
    } // end of task (closure)
    task.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: I tried it and it is working, and what if I would like to update the UI from outside the getCards() { ...}, for example a UItavbleview? It means I have to call the getCards inside the tableview?

Comment: @aspnet82, inside that closure(in update UI section) you should ask you table view to update data from the model (allCards - is your model I suppose), to do that you need to call tableView.reloadData(). This method asks the table view to ask your delegate(your Viewcontroller I suppose) about how should it fill itself. To learn more how it all plays out I recommend you to watch this super awesome tutorial about table view - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78LWmmDxr4k

Comment: @aspnet82, and about your question, may be there's no sense to update UI  outside the closure, you should get this Async Idea. If you put code after this closure, what happens. First, after your viewDidLoad, first it starts web request to get your cards at the same time it will execute code AFTER the closure in view did load, then when request will be done, it will execute closure itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the card instance inside the `for loop` and append the card in `allCard` array once you assign the values to it the method `gorCards()` should be updated as below..

```
func getCards()  {
let url = URL(string: "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards/sets/Classic?mashape-key=....")!        
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil { // if urlSession have issues manage the error here
        print(error)
    } else { // if we have data, response, error then continue here
        if let urlContent = data { // if data exist then
            do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                for cards in 0...jsonResult.count - 1 {
                 let card = Card(name: "", cost: 0, attack: 0, durability: 0, cardClass: "", cardSet: "", imageURL: "", goldenImageURL: "", type: "", mechanics: [["":""]], howToGetGolden: "")
                    if let name = jsonResult[cards]["name"] as? String {    //NAME Optionaml Bindings
                        self.card.name = name
                    } else {
                        self.card.name = ""
                    }                                                       // END Name Optionaml Bindings
                    if let cost = jsonResult[cards]["cost"] as? Int {       //COST Optionaml Bindings
                        self.card.cost = cost
                    } else {
                        self.card.cost = 0
                    }                                                        // END COST Optionaml Bindings
                    if let attack = jsonResult[cards]["attack"] as? Int {    //ATTACK Optionaml Bindings
                        self.card.attack = attack
                    } else {
                        self.card.attack = 0
                    }   
             self.allCard.append(card)
             // END TTACK Optionaml Bindings
            } catch { //catch error while parsing json
                print("error")
            }
        }
    } // end if/ELSE
} // end of task (closure)
task.resume()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle completion of URLSession dataTask like that:

- add `typealias Completion = (Void) -> Void` to your class
- add completion handler to your getCards method 
  `func getCards(completion: Completion? = nil)  {}`
- now you can call this method like this:

  `self.getCards() {
      print(self.allCard.count)
  }`
- call completion() after dataTask will be completed

  import UIKit
      class ViewController: UIViewController {

  ```
  typealias Completion = (Void) -> Void
  var allCard = [Card]()
  let card = Card(name: "", cost: 0, attack: 0, durability: 0, cardClass: "", cardSet: "", imageURL: "", goldenImageURL: "", type: "", mechanics: [["":""]], howToGetGolden: "")

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      getCards() {
          print(allCard.count)
      }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func getCards(completion: Completion? = nil)  {
      let url = URL(string: "https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards/sets/Classic?mashape-key=....")!
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
          if error != nil { // if urlSession have issues manage the error here
              print(error)
          } else { // if we have data, response, error then continue here
              if let urlContent = data { // if data exist then
                  do {
                      let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                      for cards in 0...jsonResult.count - 1 {
                          if let name = jsonResult[cards]["name"] as? String {    //NAME Optionaml Bindings
                              self.card.name = name
                          } else {
                              self.card.name = ""
                          }                                                       // END Name Optionaml Bindings
                          if let cost = jsonResult[cards]["cost"] as? Int {       //COST Optionaml Bindings
                              self.card.cost = cost
                          } else {
                              self.card.cost = 0
                          }                                                        // END COST Optionaml Bindings
                          if let attack = jsonResult[cards]["attack"] as? Int {    //ATTACK Optionaml Bindings
                              self.card.attack = attack
                          } else {
                              self.card.attack = 0
                          }                                                       // END TTACK Optionaml Bindings
                      } catch { //catch error while parsing json
                          print("error")
                      }
                  }
              } // end if/ELSE
          completion?()
          } // end of task (closure)
          task.resume()
      }
  ```

  }